# Simplify Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do I simplify the following expression with Boolean Algebra? Please show what you used to simplify so I can understand.

> $$ABC + AB'C' + ABC' + A'B'C'$$

Comment: I would go with $ABC + AB'C' + ABC' + A'B'C' = AB + B'C'$, since $A+A'=1$.

Comment: $$ABC+ABC'+AB'C'+A'B'C'=AB(C+C')+B'C'(A+A')=AB+B'C'$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I want to group the elements that are similar. This will allow me to start reducing the expression.

$$ABC + AB'C' + ABC' + A'B'C'$$
$$ABC + ABC' + AB'C' + A'B'C'$$
$$[AB(C+C')] + [B'C'(A+A')] // Group.$$
$$AB + B'C'                 // α+α' = 1; α * 1 = α $$

Edit: For me Boolean Algebra is superior, but if you ever get stuck on a problem try using a Karnaugh map: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

If you read the Wiki page you will see that with a Karnaugh map you can simplify this expression.

Comment: Liking this Karnaugh_map.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you have both $ABC$ and $ABC'$:

$$ABC+ABC'=AB(C+C')=AB\;.$$

The rest is $AB'C'+A'B'C'$, and you can use the same idea:

$$AB'C'+A'B'C'=(A+A')B'C'=B'C'\;.$$

After those simplifications the expression has been reduced to $AB+B'C'$, which is as simple as it’s going to get.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $C+C'=1$ and $X\cdot1=X$, and $X(Y+Z)=XY+XZ$. Then we have:

$$\begin{align}
&ABC+AB'C'+ABC'+A'B'C'=\\
&ABC+ABC'+AB'C'+A'B'C'=\\
&AB(C+C')+(A+A')B'C'=\\
&&=AB+B'C'
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all we will rearrange a question to make it easy.
ABC+AB′C′+ABC′+A′B′C′

```
                                                    boolean laws.
```

Solution:

```
                                                     (C+C')=1
      1)STEP:  ABC+ABC'+AB'C'+A'B'C'

      2)STEP:  AB(C+C')+(A+A')B'C'                  (A+A')=1  
      3)STEP:  AB(1)+(1)B'C'
 RESULT ANSWER:
              AB+B'C'
```

Can find boolean laws truth table on this link
[1]: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html